# Dojo.Store Observable -- ' has no method observe'

Tags: javascript, memory, dojo

I'm trying to set up a simple dojo Observable memory store, but am running into some issues.

I am currently setting up a basic store like so:

```
store = new Observable(new Memory({data: someData}));
```

And then trying to 'observe' it:

```
store.observe(function() {
    alert('something');
});
```

Here is a fiddle showing the error: http://jsfiddle.net/vGfY7/

I believe I am following both the dojo [Memory](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/Memory.html#id5) and [Observe](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/Observable.html#dojo-store-observable) documentation.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the answer is a bit strange --- you can't observe a store, but only a result set.

Therefore, you have to do something like this:

```
 var results = store.query();

 results.observe(function() {
     alert('changed');
 });
```

Here's an updated fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/vm88v/1/.